# While loop using standard input

Tags: java, input, io, while-loop, stdin

I'm trying to read in an indeterminate amount of chars into my data structure using readChar() from algs4 [StdIn.java](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/stdlib/StdIn.java.html). Amount of lines of possible input is also unknown and spaces/tabs should be disregarded.

For example, sample input

```
ABC D
EF
```

Should be read as

```
ABDCEF
```

into my structure.

I'm having a lot of trouble finding an appropriate loop(s) to get StdIn to act how I want it to and not get me stuck in an infinite loop.

Comment: How do you want it to act? Should it end on a character? Does it ask for a yes/no answer to continue? Need a little more detail than that.

Comment: Was meant for the loop to just end as soon as there was no more input to be read, i.e. a new line beginning with a blank space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file gives you quite a bit of that.  Just use the readAllLines and then combine them into one line via StringBuffer.append().  So you iterate over each line, then iterate over each charater in each line.  If it is not a space, append it to the StringBuffer.  At the end print out the toString of StringBuffer().  The code has provisions to take care of newlines (\n) and returns (\r).

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    String[] lines = StdIn.readAllLines();
    for (int i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
        String line = lines[i];
        char[] charArray = line.toCharArray();
        for (int j = 0; j < charArray.length; j++) {
            char c = charArray[j];
            if (c != ' '){
                sb.append(c);
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(sb.toString());
}
```

Ran it with:

```
ABC DEF 
XYZ
```

It output:

```
ABCDEFXYZ
```

Answer (score 1):

After typing your input you will have to hit Ctrl-Z (at least on windows running in eclipse) to tell the StdIn class that there is no more input

```
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    char c;
    while (StdIn.hasNextChar()) {
        c = StdIn.readChar();
        if (c != '\n' && c != '\r' && c != ' ') { // plus add the unicode whitespace characters mentioned in the top comment
            sb.append(c);
        }
    }

    System.out.println(sb.toString());
```